# How do I connect to mongodb with node.js (and authenticate)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, authentication, connection

How do I connect to mongodb with node.js?

I have the node-mongodb-native driver.

There's apparently 0 documentation.

Is it something like this?

```
var mongo = require('mongodb/lib/mongodb'); 
var Db= new mongo.Db( dbname, new mongo.Server( 'mongolab.com', 27017, {}), {});
```

Where do I put the username and the password?

Also how do I insert something?

Thanks.

Comment: Good places to start http://christiankvalheim.com/ and https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native That said I'm working on proper docs as we speak for the v1 release of the driver which will be the first officially supported 10gen version.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Per [the source](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/V0.8.1/lib/mongodb/db.js#L282):

After connecting:

```
Db.authenticate(user, password, function(err, res) {
  // callback
});
```

Comment: I can't believe this answer got upvoted so much with syntax errors... the callback is ill defined. See my solution and more appropriate source link below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15191273/1060487

Comment: i first tried this and it didn't work but that's because I was using it wrong. I was using the credentials of my users in admin. I created a user specifically for the database and used those credentials. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Db doesn't have authenticate method any more as of driver version 3.1. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html

Answer (score 38):

Everyone should use this source link:

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/contents.html

Answer to the question:

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID,
    Binary = require('mongodb').Binary,
    GridStore = require('mongodb').GridStore,
    Code = require('mongodb').Code,
    BSON = require('mongodb').pure().BSON,
    assert = require('assert');

var db = new Db('integration_tests', new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017,
 {auto_reconnect: false, poolSize: 4}), {w:0, native_parser: false});

// Establish connection to db
db.open(function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);

  // Add a user to the database
  db.addUser('user', 'name', function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(null, err);

    // Authenticate
    db.authenticate('user', 'name', function(err, result) {
      assert.equal(true, result);

      db.close();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would you always add the user to the database?

Comment: This is an example, copied from the driver manual link I posted... the connection method is the useful portion.

Comment: Just for information, hoping that can help somebody.. This doesn't work, because of `null != {}` and this check fails: `assert.equal(null, err);`

Comment: Perhaps the manual example is outdated now and there's a newer version of Mongo, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 16):

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;    
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+DATABASEUSERNAME+':'+DATABASEPASSWORD+'@'+DATABASEHOST+':'DATABASEPORT+'/'+DATABASENAME,function(err, db){  
      if(err) 
        console.log(err);
      else
      {
        console.log('Mongo Conn....');

      }
    });
//for local server 
//in local server DBPASSWOAD and DBusername not required
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+DATABASEHOST+':'+DATABASEPORT+'/'+DATABASENAME,function(err, db){  
      if(err) 
        console.log(err);
      else
      {
        console.log('Mongo Conn....');

      }
    });
```

Comment: perfect... thanks ... u just left concatenation operator '@'+DATABASEHOST+':' + DATABASEPORT @Viral Patel

Answer (score 9):

I find using a Mongo url handy. I store the URL in an environment variable and use that to configure servers whilst the development version uses a default url with no password.

The URL has the form:

```
export MONGODB_DATABASE_URL=mongodb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@DBHOST:DBPORT/DBNAME
```

Code to connect this way:

```
var DATABASE_URL = process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE_URL || mongodb.DEFAULT_URL;

mongo_connect(DATABASE_URL, mongodb_server_options, 
      function(err, db) { 

          if(db && !err) {
          console.log("connected to mongodb" + " " + lobby_db);
          }
          else if(err) {
          console.log("NOT connected to mongodb " + err + " " + lobby_db);
          }
      });
```

Comment: If the user is in another db than DBNAME (like admin), you must add the options `?authSource=admin` to the URL.

Answer (score 7):

My version:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:pass@dhost:port/baseName', function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    var collection = db.collection('collectionName');
    collection.find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [mongoskin](https://github.com/guileen/node-mongoskin) I just created.

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db('admin:pass@localhost/mydb?auto_reconnnect');
db.collection('mycollection').find().toArray(function(err, items){
   // do something with items
});
```

Is mongoskin sync? Nop, it is async.

Answer (score 4):

Here is new may to authenticate from "admin" and then switch to your desired DB for further operations:

```
   var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Db = require('mongodb').Db, Server = require('mongodb').Server ,
    assert = require('assert');

var user = 'user';
var password = 'password';

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://'+user+':'+password+'@localhost:27017/opsdb',{native_parser:true, authSource:'admin'}, function(err,db){
    if(err){
        console.log("Auth Failed");
        return;
    }
    console.log("Connected");
    db.collection("cols").find({loc:{ $eq: null } }, function(err, docs) {
        docs.each(function(err, doc) {
          if(doc) {
            console.log(doc['_id']);
          }
        });
    });

    db.close();

});
```

Comment: That is just the connection name for db.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Db.admin().authenticate(user, password, function() {} );
```

Comment: Does not work on newer versions of the driver. The db.authenticate() method no longer exists. At least, it doesn't exist in the node.js 3.1 driver I'm using. I get "db.authenticate is not a function" error in the Node Inspector console.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
var db = require('mongo-lite').connect('mongodb://localhost/test')
```

[more details ...](http://alexeypetrushin.github.com/mongo-lite)

Comment: Love this library. Elements some callbacks. Even a better fit than mongo-skin

Answer (score 1):

if you continue to have problems with the native driver, you can also check out sleepy mongoose.  It's a python REST server that you can simply access with node request to get to your Mongo instance.
http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/02/22/sleepy-mongoose-a-mongodb-rest-interface/

Answer (score 1):

With the link provided by @mattdlockyer as reference, this worked for me:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongo.Server(host, port, options);
db = new mongo.Db(mydb, server, {fsync:true});
db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to database");
        db.authenticate(user, password, function(err, res) {
            if(!err) {
                console.log("Authenticated");
            } else {
                console.log("Error in authentication.");
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Error in open().");
        console.log(err);
    };
});

exports.testMongo = function(req, res){
    db.collection( mycollection, function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight typo with Chris' answer.

```
Db.authenticate(user, password, function({ // callback }));
```

should be

```
Db.authenticate(user, password, function(){ // callback } );
```

Also depending on your mongodb configuration, you may need to connect to admin and auth there first before going to a different database. This will be the case if you don't add a user to the database you're trying to access. Then you can auth via admin and then switch db and then read or write at will.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
// import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myProject';

async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('documents');

  // the following code examples can be pasted here...

  return 'done.';
}

main()
   //what to do next
  .then(console.log)
   //if there is an error
  .catch(console.error)
  // what to do in the end(function result won't matter here, it will execute always).
  .finally(() => client.close());
```

you can find more in the documentation here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/

Answer (score -2):

I'm using Mongoose to connect to mongodb.
Install mongoose npm using following command

> npm install mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/database_name', function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log('database not connected');
    }
});
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userschema = new Schema ({});
var user = mongoose.model('collection_name', userschema);
```

we can use the queries like this

```
user.find({},function(err,data){
         if(err){
         console.log(err);
         }
        console.log(data);
    });
```